# how to pause the onEdit function in googlescript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a problem that I would easily solve with global variables, but I do not know how to face here since they do not exist, as far as I know
My goal is to pause a onEdit(event) function with a button, so that for a minute i can edit my sheet without creating a mess.

I use a function onEdit(event) to automatically add the entrance and exit time of people in a sheet
when I have to edit the sheets for some reasons, but I am not inserting any new person in the sheet, the onEdit catches every edit as the insertion of a person, and the sheet becomes a mess.
I was wondering how I could do a 1 minute break into the script, by calling it with an external button, called "WAIT1MINUTE".

I can create the button this way:

```
function onOpen(){
var ui=SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
ui.createMenu('Wait')
.addItem('Wait','WAIT1MINUTE')
.addToUi();}
```

what I would do with a global variable is the following

```
global a=1; //automatic completion is ON
function WAIT1MINUTE{
  a=0;  //automatic completion is OFF
  Utilities.sleep(60000);
  a=1;//automatic completion is ON
}

function onEdit(event,a){
  if(a) { //automatic completion is ON
  // do the automatic completion of time entrance and exit
  }
}
```

Comment: You may take a look at [Properties class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties) instead of global varibale.

Comment: Thank you @Pierre-MarieRichard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in Pierre's comment, you want to use the PropertiesService.

```
function WAIT1MINUTE() {
  PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().setProperty('a', 0);
  Utilities.sleep(60000);
  PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().setProperty('a', 1);
}

function onEdit(event){
  var a = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperty('a');

  if(a) { //automatic completion is ON
  // do the automatic completion of time entrance and exit
  }
}
```

Comment: Be careful, onEdit method take only 1 argument.

Comment: Good point @Pierre-MarieRichard! I forgot to remove that from the original code. Fixed it.

Comment: I added this short script and the relative button to ensure that the autocompletation was on  
`function autoComplete_ON(){
  var documentProperties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
  documentProperties.setProperty('a', '1');}`

I also changed from `if (a)` to `if (a>0)`